# run a c# program in the background continuously on a computer

Tags: c#

I have the code below as an example, but would like to know how i could run the console .exe file indefinitely but run the for loop on five minute increment..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hellow world");                    
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `while ( true )` then return false after 5 minutes has passed.

Comment: how would you do this

Comment: You can use `DateTime.Now` to get the current time, or use the `Stopwatch` class to be more accurate.

Comment: @user2543131 - Your current code only loops 10 times.  Get to the point where the loop is infinite.  Your previous question's answers explain how to do that.

Comment: You already asked this, and you already accepted an answer.  Why are you asking again?

Comment: @abelenky, thanks for posting this.  I was wondering where all the downvotes were coming from

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Thread.Sleep:

```
Thread.Sleep(300000);
```

Where the number is the number of milliseconds you want to wait. I wouldn't recommend using a console application to do this though.  Have you looked at creating a windows service?

Answer (score 1):

I would run it as a Windows Scheduled Task.  This way you don't have to re-implement all the scheduling options in your own application. So, the steps would be:

1. Write a simple console application that executes your logic once and then exits
2. Create a Scheduled Task to run your application at regular intervals.  (**[Documentation is here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task)**)